# How to sniff iphone network data

Tags: iphone, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I have recently been having problems with my app and I need to view the data being sent to and from my iPhone. I have read about Paros and downloaded it, but I don't know what information I need to put into paros and my iPhone to make it work. I am running a normal windows 7 installation with no current proxy server and my ISP is telus with the fiber optics package. So what do I need to install and where do I find all of the information needed to read the data being sent over the network by my iPhone using paros?

Comment: Yea, why did it get downvoted? There are many question simmilar to this, but the answers didn't have enough info. I have been searching for a very long time to try and figure this out but on any other question site nobody even answered. I have searched to figure this out but there is no sufficient data out there for me to figure this out.

Comment: COME ON!!! Now my rep is back to one because I use this site how I'm supposed to.

Comment: ppl should really own up to their downvote - it's a SO recommendation. Play fair people

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming-related questions. You probably want Super User instead.

Comment: @Bavarious. Programmers are likely to have some ideas how this can be done. Seems still relevant to ask on SO (imho)

Comment: Yea, and there are already many questions on sniffing packets on this site, but none about how to find the info. It would be nice if somone just TOLD ME HOW TO USE PAROS INSTEAD OF DEBATING WHETHER THIS IS A VALID QUESTION OR NOT, IT IS!!!

Comment: Sorry Alex, that was me - I meant to click the star after flagging the post as off-topic but clicked the down arrow instead; then learnt that up-voting doesn't restore to zero but essentially add plus one (kind of like a plus two, really). I'll bump it up if you edit the post, since it has been over an hour.

Comment: Yea, I guess that's alright. It isn't like my question is of any importance, cause apperantly there is something about me that I somehow don't deserve to have any assistance with a problem I have had and spent countless hours trying to fix. Thanks guys    /*SARCASM*\

Comment: I don't think they were saying it was a bad question - just as some people believed it was not a *programming* question, which is what this board is limited to. I think it is a totally valid programming question. I think I asked one similar a while back. People need to do this kind of thing to debug stuff. (I up-voted to counteract.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do this a lot. I do it with a MacBook, but I'm sure you can use a similar technique to do it from windows:

1. Connect your PC to a hard-wired ethernet to the outside world.
2. Set your PC up for internet sharing. (This is the big thing that will work differently between the Mac and PC). Set up to share your *Hard-wired Connection* with people from your *WiFi Connection*. Your computer will then become a wireless access point.
3. Connect your iPhone to use your PC as it's WiFi network
4. Download and run Wireshark (Open Source - Publicly available) on your PC. Wireshark will sniff and log the network traffic.

You can then obviously set up whatever rules your would like to limit your network trace to only your iPhone.

Like I said - I do this all the time with a MacBook and it's easy and powerful!

Comment: Thanks, i figured that would work, but my ethernet port is fried, I guess I have to find one that works.